# Enabling time dimension for layers in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, layers, time, dimensions

I have a collection of GeoTIFF files, each one corresponding to a date and time.

How can I add the information date and time to those GeoTIFF, so that GeoServer allows the enabling the "Time" dimension for this layer?

I have followed this link : https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html, but this won't work properly, it will work for up to date (day only), the time property has not been added to the layers
I have used GeoServer version 2.18.1
For enabling the time dimension I have used the below configuration files which are not working

- timeregex.properties:

  ```
   regex=[0-9]{8}
  ```
- indexer.properties:

  ```
  TimeAttribute=ingestion
  Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
  PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
  ```

My tiff file naming conversion is:
`cloud_20081031T122415000Z.tiff`

After adding the layers in GeoServer, the time has been not added for layers
for Example it will be like this : `2008-10-31T00:00:00.000Z`

For Leaflet animation and playback this time is needed.

When I am creating time series layer with the `timeregex.properties` as like below mentioned

- timeregex.properties:

  ```
  regex=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z
  ```

while creating the stores, the GeoServer throwing error as given below :

```
"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/Time_series_data and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@731badc1 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@36aeed56[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@281f23f2 COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null"
```

I need to create the layer with time and date as per the below
2014-12-01T06:30:23Z,2014-12-01T09:00:00Z

Comment: Do you use a shapefile as an index? Shapefile does not support times in the DATE field. You should maybe save the index into PostGIS.

Comment: Thank you, I am not using shape file, i am using GeoTiff file with indexer and timeregex property files, kindly share the procedure for adding the time series image mosaic in geoserver with date and time enabled layer. I followed the below mentioned link : https://www.earder.com/tutorials/timeseries-with-geoserver-and-openlayers/

Comment: So you do not have an automatically created shapefile in the same directory where you have the .properties file? I thought that the .properties is not enough but I may be wrong. Have you read also this document https://geoserver-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html?

Comment: Thank you, i followed the same document what you suggested, the shapefile was automatically created where the property files stored when the stores creation in geoserver, but after publish if i download the getcapabilities document then i searched the layer name, it was showing with date , not showing with time, time field is empty

Comment: Back to my first comment, if the shapefile is the place where the actual dates are stored (open the shapefile with QGIS or something and check the attributes for checking) then the times are lost because shapefile supports only dates, not times. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm `Date fields only support date. They do not support time. Avoid using shapefiles for any kind of temporal analysis or date time calculation.`.

Comment: As you said the shapefiles are not supporting time, Then which way i can store the time and date enabled image mosaic in geoserver

Comment: I suggested already to use PostGIS database and this tutorial is about that https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html.